# Datastore query for locations within a region

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

Question 1:

I am using Google Datastore (Java Client Libraries) with App Engine Flex and I am storing location data. I would like to query for a list of locations within a rectangular region.

My location entity looks like this:

```
Location
  - lat (eg. -56.1)
  - long (eg. 45.6)
```

Google Datastore has limitations for querying with multiple inequalities on different properties so I can't query using GQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE lat <= @maxLat AND lat >= @minLat AND long <= @maxLong AND long >= @minLong
```

Where `maxLat`, `minLat`, `maxLong`, and `minLong` represent the bounding rectangle to search for Locations.

Currently I am querying using just one filter:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE lat <= @maxLat AND lat >= @minLat
```

And from the returned results, I filter out the ones within the longitude bounds as well. Is there a better way to do this without resorting to this strategy ?

Question 2:

If I store the latitude/longitude combination as a Geopoint in Google Datastore, how can I check the latitude and longitude ?

For example if the location is stored like this:

```
Location
  - location (Geopoint)
```

I cannot filter on the lat/long within the Geopoint using the Java Client Libraries.

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE location.long <= @maxLong
```

Is there a workaround for the Datastore Geopoint property ?

Answer (score 2):

For an example of how to do this, look at the '[geomodel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geomodel/0.1.0)' library in Python.

## Basic premise:

Divide your latitude and longitude values into discrete values (for example, 1 degree blocks), there by defining 'cells' that the value is contained in. Combine/hash then together so you have a single value.

Now, you can convert your queries for locations in a bounded rectangle by doing equality filters against these cells. Post filter at the end if your bounded rectangle doesn't entirely line up with the cell edges.

A related example for doing this with time is: [Is datastore good for storing hr shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695582/is-datastore-good-for-storing-hr-shifts)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by this strategy. I use 1 degree cells with cell 0 representing lat: -90.0 to -89.0 and long: -180.0 to -179.0. The cell number increases every time the lat increases, and once lat reaches 89.0 to 90.0, it goes back to -90.0 to -89.0 and ups the long by 1 degree. Then the location (0, 0) is represented by being within the cell 32,399 (The location is a corner of four different cells. Which cell is it 'in'?). Is this what you're suggesting ? If the bounding box is a very small box, would the cells have to be very specific ? (0.0001 degree blocks)

Comment: I've been thinking long and hard on this one, but I still do not fully grasp your solution. Could you expand a little bit more and maybe show an example solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

Check out Datastore's REST API. There is an explicit value type for geopoints which you can find documented at the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#Value

All you'll need to do then is create a geopoint value property (let's call it geo) on an entity and then you'll be able to write GQL queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Address WHERE geo.latitude <= @maxLat AND geo.latitude >= @minLat
```